# How should I invoke webpack to bundle bazel's ts_library output

Tags: webpack, bazel, bazel-rules-nodejs

I'm trying to build a React JS app from Typescript sources, built with Bazel and using Webpack as the bundler. rules_nodejs includes [examples/react_webpack](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/tree/stable/examples/react_webpack), which shows how to do it using `ts_project`, but I need to build it using `ts_library` because `ts_project` doesn't seem to do well with generated TS files (in my case protobuf TS files).

How do I get `ts_library` to play nice with Webpack (or vice versa)?

[Here](https://github.com/simmonmt/rules_nodejs/commit/c2f1fdb279b7832c4577b8142e4d621445198451) is my attempt to adapt examples/react_webpack to use `ts_library` instead of `ts_project`. It uses Webpack 4 because that's what the example uses, and I wanted to minimize change. For completeness, I also have [this commit](https://github.com/simmonmt/rules_nodejs/commit/086e314b74133dafaab07ce1cbac2e9074c07bc3) which reproduces the change with Webpack 5, though it's my first time using Webpack 5 so it's possible that I introduced additional problems with the migration.

When I run `bazel run server` with the Webpack 4 commit, then load the resulting page in Chrome, I get this error on console:

```
app.bundle.js:6 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'
    at n (app.bundle.js:6)
    at app.bundle.js:6
    at app.bundle.js:6
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js:6)
    at n (app.bundle.js:1)
    at app.bundle.js:1
    at app.bundle.js:1
```

Webpack 5 emits a similar error, though slightly more informative(?):

```
_sync:2 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'
    at webpackEmptyContext (_sync:2)
    at eval (index.tsx:7)
    at eval (index.js:3)
    at eval (index.js:12)
    at Object../bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/index.js (main.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:172)
    at main.js:188
    at main.js:189
```

In both cases, I hit a webpack require for `./bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/index.js`, which is what I've designated as my entry point (not sure if that's the right path to have specified as the entry point). This leads me into the `index.js` AMD(?) module, which then requires `./bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin sync recursive`. That requirement seems to lead directly to the error:

```
/***/ "./bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin sync recursive":
/*!******************************************!*\
  !*** ./bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/ sync ***!
  \******************************************/
/***/ ((module) => {

eval("function webpackEmptyContext(req) {\n\tvar e = new Error(\"Cannot find module '\" + req + \"'\");\n\te.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';\n\tthrow e;\n}\nwebpackEmptyContext.keys = () => [];\nwebpackEmptyContext.resolve = webpackEmptyContext;\nwebpackEmptyContext.id = \"./bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin sync recursive\";\nmodule.exports = webpackEmptyContext;\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/_sync?");
```

One other thing I noticed:

The rules_nodejs examples/react_webpack example, using `ts_project`, compiles `index.tsx` like this:

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var styles = require("./styles.css");
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("h1", { className: styles.h1 }, "Hello, world!"), document.getElementById("root"));
s
```

I think that's a script?

`ts_library` compiles it like this, which I think is a module?

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define("react_webpack/index", ["require", "exports", "react", "react-dom"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    const React = require("react");
    const ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello, world!"), document.getElementById("root"));
});
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJmaWxlIjoiaW5kZXguanMiLCJzb3VyY2VSb290IjoiIiwic291cmNlcyI6WyIuLi8uLi8uLi9pbmRleC50c3giXSwibmFtZXMiOltdLCJtYXBwaW5ncyI6Ijs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7SUFBQSwrQkFBK0I7SUFDL0Isc0NBQXNDO0lBRXRDLFFBQVEsQ0FBQyxNQUFNLENBQ2IsZ0RBQXNCLEVBQ3RCLFFBQVEsQ0FBQyxjQUFjLENBQUMsTUFBTSxDQUFDLENBQ2hDLENBQUMiLCJzb3VyY2VzQ29udGVudCI6WyJpbXBvcnQgKiBhcyBSZWFjdCBmcm9tIFwicmVhY3RcIjtcbmltcG9ydCAqIGFzIFJlYWN0RE9NIGZyb20gXCJyZWFjdC1kb21cIjtcblxuUmVhY3RET00ucmVuZGVyKFxuICA8aDE+SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkITwvaDE+LFxuICBkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZChcInJvb3RcIilcbik7XG4iXX0=
```

Is that difference the root of the problem? Should I be trying to figure out why/how `ts_project` uses the simpler form, then convince `ts_library` to do the same thing? Or is it better to tell Webpack to bundle the `ts_library` outputs as-is? If the latter, how?

**EDIT:** The `ts_library` rule seems to be using a tsconfig of its own devising that sets `compilerOptions.module` to `umd`. Setting the same option in the `ts_project` version causes `index.js` to grow all the factory goo shown above.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that `ts_library` defaults its `devmode_module` parameter to `umd`. Webpack, at least as configured in the rules_nodejs example (i.e. without UMD-specific plugins) doesn't seem to be able to handle the UMD modules generated by `ts_library`. Changing `devmode_module` to `es2015` solves the problem. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it results in Webpack creating a functional bundled JS file.